# Make a screen blink / flash to alert user

Tags: winforms, animation, notifications, screen, blink

Using .NET 3.5 Winforms, How would i make the entire screen flash/blink between red and white for just a second.

I have a big screen that's only meant to show status on monitored equipment. I would like it to flash as a notification to users when an event occurs that they should be looking at.

Thank you

Comment: Ever noticed that programs you use everyday never do this?  Large flashing surfaces are a trigger for people prone to suffer epileptic seizures.  Oops.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I understand this would be annoying if it occured on a user's desktop. There are screens that are 20 feet away for each production line monitoring some equipment. By flashing when alerts detected it will provide staff a quick visualization of any line that has an isue for them to do further investigation since they may not be staring at their screens all day and night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use what tbischel has suggested.  Here is some sample code for the timer.

```
Private TickCount As Integer = 0
Private Const NUMBER_OF_SECONDS As Integer = 1

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.BackColor = If(Me.BackColor = Color.White, Color.Red, Color.White)
    TickCount += 1

    If TickCount >= NUMBER_OF_SECONDS * 1000 / Timer1.Interval Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        Me.BackColor = Color.Gray
        Me.TopMost = False
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    End If
End Sub
```

It will alternate between Red and White and whatever interval you specify for your timer.  It will stop after how ever many seconds you give it.  When it is done it sets the color to grey, removes the .TopMost flag and sets the WindowState back to normal.

Having said that; it's really annoying :)

Answer (score 2):

you could create a blank maximized form with the FormBorderStyle set to FormBorderStyle.None, and set the background color on a timer.